# Apache Tomcat/10.0.23 Servlet HTTP Status 404 – Not Found but works on localhost

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, http-status-code-404

After deploying the webapp to a remote server all servlets return HTTP Status 404 but index.jsp works fine.
All servlets work on localhost, running the same version of tomcat. Logs are:

catalina.out

```
10-Feb-2023 04:19:42.728 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-86] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/bitnami/tomcat/webapps/test-api.war]
10-Feb-2023 04:19:43.296 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-86] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
10-Feb-2023 04:19:43.306 INFO [ajp-nio-127.0.0.1-8009-exec-86] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/bitnami/tomcat/webapps/test-api.war] has finished in [577] ms
```

localhost_access_log

```
- [10/Feb/2023:04:08:03 +0000] "GET /test-api/test HTTP/1.1" 404 778
- [10/Feb/2023:04:19:54 +0000] "GET /test-api/test-two HTTP/1.1" 404 772
```

web.xml

```
type he<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
  version="3.0">

  <display-name>Test API</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextPath</param-name>
    <param-value>/test-api</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.servlets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>TestServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.servlets.TestServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>TestServletTwo</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test-two</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

TestServlet.java

```
package com.fourdcontrols.servlets;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@WebServlet("/test")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.getWriter().write("Testing?");
    }

}
```

Comment: (1) Apache Tomcat/10.0.23  use `jakarta.servlet` not `javax.servlet` (2) Check all log files under the tomcat/logs directory for error messages?

Comment: your web.xml is config  `com.example.servlets.TestServlet`,  but in TestServlet.java package is `com.fourdcontrols.servlets`. Maybe you can change your web.xml config to correct servlet:  `com.fourdcontrols.servlets.TestServlet`